# What is the subtle difference between "and so on" and "and so forth"?

Tags: idioms

Kurt Vonnegut uses "and so on" a good deal to end his sentences in *Breakfast of Champions*.

> In some places people would actually try to eat mud or such on gravel
> while babies were being born just a few feet away. **And so on**.

> Of all the creatures in the Universe, only Dwayne was thinking and
> feeling and worrying and planning **and so on**.

> It said to simply anybody, in effect, “Hey—guess what: You’re the
> only creature with free will. How does that make you feel?”
> **And so on.**

> He would get down on the floor and roll around with Sparky, and he
> would say things like, “You and me, Spark,” and “How’s my old buddy?"
> **and so on.**

> He would kid Bill about that. “How’s the old respiration, Bill?” he’d
> say, or, “Seems like you’ve got a touch of the old emphysema, Bill,”
> or, “We never discussed what kind of a funeral you want, Bill. You
> never even told me what your religion is.” **And so on**.

> The expression was first used by news photographers, who often got to
> see up women’s skirts at accidents and sporting events and from
> underneath fire escapes **and so on.**

> “Vern’s wife thinks Vem is trying to turn her brains into plutonium,” said
> Dwayne. “What’s plutonium?” said Harry, **and so on.**

My editor once changed my "and so on" to "and so forth" in a story.

Why?

Comment: Did you ask your editor?

Comment: “and so on” appears to be more commonly use than “and so forth” which is probably a bit more formal in usage. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+so+on%2C+and+so+forth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cand%20so%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cand%20so%20forth%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Some even chain the phrases together - and so on, and so forth.

Comment: Your editor thought that *and so forth* was somehow more appropriate to the style of whatever the publication was. While it is debatable whether the editor was right about that, the fact that *and so on* fitted well the style of Vonegut's prose, is not dispostive of whether it fits well the style of some different text.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a difference in meaning according to any dictionary I consulted. Collins, Macmillan, Dictionary.com (American Heritage), Cambridge, and Merriam-Webster all either define one in terms of the other ("**and so on**: and so forth") or have a joint entry for both terms. Different people may have personal prejudices, and may feel "forth" sounds more sophisticated or fancy, or may prefer the simple language of "and so on".

**References**:

- [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/and-so-forth)
- [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/and-so-on-forth)
- [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/and--so--forth)
- [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and-so-on)
- [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/and%20so%20forth)